# locomotive.js smooth scroll wrong viewport height

Tags: javascript, smooth-scrolling

I use locomotive.js (https://locomotivemtl.github.io/locomotive-scroll/) on a wordpress site and I ran into an annoying mistake: when navigate to a dynamically loaded page (i.e. portfolio archive page), locomotive incorrectly calculates the viewport height amd the page smaller than it should be. After change the window size it suddenly improves... I come to realize that the js initialized before the loading of the DOM elements is over (I use vanilla javascript). So I tried this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
        el: document.querySelector('[data-scroll-container]'),
        smooth: true,
        smoothMobile: false
    });
});
```

It didn't work. After some research I find this forum: https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll/issues/31 - Here is the thing: "You need to destroy the instance of the scroll plugin using scroll.destroy(); and initialize it every time a page is loaded." - I can't figure it out how to do that, could anyone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
    el: document.querySelector('[data-scroll-container]'),
    smooth: true,
    smoothMobile: false
});
scroll.destroy();
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    scroll.init();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Евгений Иванов for your reply. I already use another Smooth Scroll js.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this problem after dynamic page load without browser loading and using some third library or router system. Can you share the stack or package.json file. That will help me post the right answer if I got one?

or you can try this:

```js
function smooth() {
    let scrollContainer = document.querySelector('your-selector');
    scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
        el: scrollContainer,
        smooth: true    });

    setTimeout(() => {
        scroll.update();
    }, 500); // 500 is 0.5s of wait for scroll to update after calling it, you can change it to make sure that it run after new DOM has loaded otherwise scroll.update() will run but before new DOM has loaded and will have no effect on new DOM / content
}

// calling scroll on first load
let scroll;

// when ever you are leaving the current page, destroy the scroll before leave
scroll.destroy();

// when ever you are entering new page, call smooth function after new DOM has loaded that will update your scroll
smooth();
```

Happy Coding

Comment: Thank you Shehzad Asif for your reply. I already use another Smooth Scroll js.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and I fixed like below:

```
let locoScroll;
locoScroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
  el: document.querySelector("[data-scroll-container]"),
  smooth: true,
});
new ResizeObserver(() => locoScroll.update()).observe(
  document.querySelector("[data-scroll-container]")
);
```

here is the link of solution on GitHub [check it out](https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll/issues/408)